# Making A Console For A Java Text Based Game

Tags: java, console

So, Iv'e been trying to make a simple Text Based RPG with Java, and it is going quite well, and my friends want to play it too but they aren't very tech savvy, so it's hard to tell them to get an IDE or use the CMD, so I wanted to know if there was a way to make my text-based game into a window, like using JFrame or something. All i need is a window that displays the text, and a bar on the bottom that lets the user input what they want (Kind of like a CMD). I do not know how to do this as of yet, because I am quite new at coding, can anyone help me? And it could be like a simple console because im not looking for a complex GUI or anything at the moment.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

private static String command, commandAttack, commandShop;
private static int monsterRat = 100;
private static int monsterWeasel = 110;
private static int monsterBear = 120;
private static int hp = 100;
private static int level = 0;
private static int mana = 10;
private static int expTotal = 0;
private static int goldTotal = 0;
private static int commandItem, commandBuy, arrow,
        shuriken, bomb, hpPotion, mpPotion, potion, items;
public Skills skillObject = new Skills();

public static void title(){
    System.out.println("Welcome To My First Game!");
}
    //BEGINNING OF MONSTERS
    //First Monster - Easy
public static void huntRat(){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("A Monster Appeared! Its a Wild Rat! ");
    do
    {
    System.out.print("What Skill do you want to use?"
        + "\nBasic,Heal,Item,Run: ");
    commandAttack = console.next();
    System.out.println("");
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Run")){
        game();
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")){
        int attack = (int)(15 + Math.random()*40-15+1);
        System.out.println("-You have done: "
            + attack + " damage");
        monsterRat = monsterRat - attack;
        System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
            + monsterRat + " HP left!\n");
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Heal") && mana >= 2){
        int healing = (int)(10 + Math.random()*35-10+1);
        hp = Math.min(hp + healing, 100);
        mana = Math.max(mana - 2, 0);
        System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
            + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n"
                + "Mana: " + mana + "/10\n");
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Item") && items >= 1){
        System.out.println("Choose what to use::\n");
        System.out.println("1. Arrow: " + arrow + "\n"
                + "2. Shurkiken: " + shuriken + "\n"
                + "3. Bombs: " + bomb + "\n"
                + "4. Small HP-Potion: " + hpPotion + "\n"
                + "5. Mana-Potion: " + mpPotion + "\n"
                + "6. Large HP-Potion: " + potion + "\n");
        commandItem = console.nextInt();
        if(commandItem == 1 && arrow >= 1){
            System.out.println("You fire an arrow at the monster!");
            int attack = 20;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterRat = monsterRat - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterRat + " HP left!\n");
            arrow--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 2 && shuriken >= 1){
            System.out.println("You throw a shuriken at the monster!");
            int attack = 40;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterRat = monsterRat - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterRat + " HP left!\n");
            shuriken--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 3 && bomb >= 1){
            System.out.println("-You throw a bomb at the monster!");
            int attack = 60;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterRat = monsterRat - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterRat + " HP left!\n");
            bomb--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 4 && hpPotion >= 1){
            int healing = 20;
            hp = hp + healing;
            System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
                    + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n");
            hpPotion--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 5 && mpPotion >= 1){
            mana = 10;
            System.out.println("-You now have 10/10 mana!");
            mpPotion--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 6 && potion >= 1){
            int healing = 40;
            hp = hp + healing;
            System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
                    + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n");
            potion--;
        }
    }
    if(monsterRat > 0){
        int dmg = (int)(10 + Math.random()*25-10+1);
        hp = hp - dmg; 
        System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has done: " + dmg 
                + " HP of damage to you!\n" + "-You have: "
                + hp + "hp left!\n");
        }
    if(hp <= 0){ //Die = GameOver
        System.out.println("-You have died! Game Over!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    mana = Math.min(mana + 1, 10);
        }
    while(monsterRat >= 1);
    //after battle if wins
    int expRat = (int)(5 + Math.random()*50-5+1);
    int goldRat = (int)(5 + Math.random()*10-5+1);
    goldTotal = goldTotal + goldRat;
    expTotal = expTotal + expRat;
    System.out.println("You have gotten: " + expRat
        + " EXP!\nYou picked up: "
        + goldRat + " gold!\n");
    monsterRat = 100;
    }
    //Second Monster - Intermediate
public static void huntWeasel(){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("A Monster Appeared! Its a Wild Weasel! ");
    do
    {
    System.out.print("What Skill do you want to use?"
        + "\nBasic,Heal,Item,Run: ");
    commandAttack = console.next();
    System.out.println("");
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Run")){
        game();
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")){
        int attack = (int)(15 + Math.random()*40-15+1);
        System.out.println("-You have done: "
            + attack + " damage");
        monsterWeasel = monsterWeasel - attack;
        System.out.println("-The Wild Weasel has: "
            + monsterWeasel + " HP left!\n");
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Heal") && mana >= 2){
        int healing = (int)(10 + Math.random()*35-10+1);
        hp = Math.min(hp + healing, 100);
        mana = Math.max(mana - 2, 0);
        System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
            + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n"
                + "Mana: " + mana + "/10\n");
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Item") && items >= 1){
        System.out.println("Choose what to use::\n");
        System.out.println("1. Arrow: " + arrow + "\n"
                + "2. Shurkiken: " + shuriken + "\n"
                + "3. Bombs: " + bomb + "\n"
                + "4. Small HP-Potion: " + hpPotion + "\n"
                + "5. Mana-Potion: " + mpPotion + "\n"
                + "6. Large HP-Potion: " + potion + "\n");
        commandItem = console.nextInt();
        if(commandItem == 1 && arrow >= 1){
            System.out.println("You fire an arrow at the monster!");
            int attack = 20;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterWeasel = monsterWeasel - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterWeasel + " HP left!\n");
            arrow--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 2 && shuriken >= 1){
            System.out.println("You throw a shuriken at the monster!");
            int attack = 40;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterWeasel = monsterWeasel - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterWeasel + " HP left!\n");
            shuriken--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 3 && bomb >= 1){
            System.out.println("You throw a bomb at the monster!");
            int attack = 60;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterWeasel = monsterWeasel - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterWeasel + " HP left!\n");
            bomb--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 4 && hpPotion >= 1){
            int healing = 20;
            hp = hp + healing;
            System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
                    + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n");
            hpPotion--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 5 && mpPotion >= 1){
            mana = 10;
            System.out.println("-You now have 10/10 mana!");
            mpPotion--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 6 && potion >= 1){
            int healing = 40;
            hp = hp + healing;
            System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
                    + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n");
            potion--;
        }
    }
    if(monsterWeasel > 0){
        int dmg = (int)(10 + Math.random()*30-10+1);
        hp = hp - dmg; 
        System.out.println("-The Wild Weasel has done: " + dmg 
                + " HP of damage to you!\n" + "-You have: " + hp + "hp left!\n");
        }
    if(hp <= 0){ //Die = GameOver
        System.out.println("-You have died! Game Over!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    mana = Math.min(mana + 1, 10);
        }
    while(monsterWeasel >= 1);
    //after battle if wins
    int expWeasel = (int)(20 + Math.random()*75-20+1);
    int goldWeasel = (int)(10 + Math.random()*30-10+1);
    goldTotal = goldTotal + goldWeasel;
    expTotal = expTotal + expWeasel;
    System.out.println("You have gotten: " + expWeasel
        + " EXP!\nYou picked up: "
        + goldWeasel + " gold!\n");
    monsterWeasel = 110;
    }
    //Third Monster - Hardest
public static void huntBear(){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("A Monster Appeared! Its a Wild Bear! ");
    do
    {
    System.out.print("What Skill do you want to use?"
        + "\nBasic,Heal,Item,Run: ");
    commandAttack = console.next();
    System.out.println("");
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Run")){
        game();
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")){
        int attack = (int)(15 + Math.random()*40-15+1);
        System.out.println("-You have done: "
            + attack + " damage");
        monsterBear = monsterBear - attack;
        System.out.println("-The Wild Bear has: "
            + monsterBear + " HP left!\n");
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Heal") && mana >= 2){
        int healing = (int)(10 + Math.random()*35-10+1);
        hp = Math.min(hp + healing, 100);
        mana = Math.max(mana - 2, 0);
        System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
            + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n"
                + "Mana: " + mana + "/10\n");
        }
    if(commandAttack.equalsIgnoreCase("Item") && items >= 1){
        System.out.println("Choose what to use::\n");
        System.out.println("1. Arrow: " + arrow + "\n"
                + "2. Shurkiken: " + shuriken + "\n"
                + "3. Bombs: " + bomb + "\n"
                + "4. Small HP-Potion: " + hpPotion + "\n"
                + "5. Mana-Potion: " + mpPotion + "\n"
                + "6. Large HP-Potion: " + potion + "\n");
        commandItem = console.nextInt();
        if(commandItem == 1 && arrow >= 1){
            System.out.println("You fire an arrow at the monster!");
            int attack = 20;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterBear = monsterBear - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterBear + " HP left!\n");
            arrow--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 2 && shuriken >= 1){
            System.out.println("You throw a shuriken at the monster!");
            int attack = 40;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterBear = monsterBear - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterBear + " HP left!\n");
            shuriken--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 3 && bomb >= 1){
            System.out.println("You throw a bomb at the monster!");
            int attack = 60;
            System.out.println("-You have done: "
                    + attack + " damage");
            monsterBear = monsterBear - attack;
            System.out.println("-The Wild Rat has: "
                    + monsterBear + " HP left!\n");
            bomb--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 4 && hpPotion >= 1){
            int healing = 20;
            hp = hp + healing;
            System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
                    + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n");
            hpPotion--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 5 && mpPotion >= 1){
            mana = 10;
            System.out.println("-You now have 10/10 mana!");
            mpPotion--;
        }
        if(commandItem == 6 && potion >= 1){
            int healing = 40;
            hp = hp + healing;
            System.out.println("-You have healed: " + healing 
                    + "\n-You have now: " + hp + " hp!\n");
            potion--;
        }
    }
    if(monsterBear > 0){
        int dmg = (int)(14 + Math.random()*35-14+1);
        hp = hp - dmg; 
        System.out.println("-The Wild Bear has done: " + dmg 
                + " HP of damage to you!\n" 
                + "-You have: " + hp + "hp left!\n");
        }
    if(hp <= 0){ //Die = GameOver
        System.out.println("-You have died! Game Over!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    mana = Math.min(mana + 1, 10);
        }
    while(monsterBear >= 1);
    //after battle if wins
    int expBear = (int)(40 + Math.random()*120-40+1);
    int goldBear = (int)(30 + Math.random()*50-30+1);
    goldTotal = goldTotal + goldBear;
    expTotal = expTotal + expBear;
    System.out.println("You have gotten: " + expBear
        + " EXP!\nYou picked up: "
        + goldBear + " gold!\n");
    monsterBear = 120;
    }
    //END OF MONSTERS

public static void shop(){
    do
    {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("----------------------------\nWhat do you want to"
            + " shop for? | Weapons | Items | Magic | Leave |\n"
            + "Choice: ");
    commandShop = console.next();
    System.out.println();
    if(commandShop.equalsIgnoreCase("Weapons")){
        System.out.print("What do you want to buy?\n1. Arrow - 10g"
                + " DMG: 20 (lvl: 0)\n2. Shuriken - 20g DMG: 40 (lvl: 1)"
                + "\n3. Bomb - 40g DMG: 60 (lvl: 2)\n"
                + "Choice: ");
        commandBuy = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        if(commandBuy == 1 && goldTotal >= 10){
            arrow++;
            items++;
            goldTotal = goldTotal - 10;
            System.out.println("You now have: " + arrow + " Arrow(s)!\n"
                    + "You now have: " + goldTotal + " gold!\n");
        }
        if(commandBuy == 2 && goldTotal >= 20 && level >= 1){
            shuriken++;
            items++;
            goldTotal = goldTotal - 20;
            System.out.println("You now have: " + shuriken 
                    + " Shuriken(s)!\n"
                    + "You now have: " + goldTotal + " gold!\n");
        }
        if(commandBuy == 3 && goldTotal >= 40 && level >= 2){
            bomb++;
            items++;
            goldTotal = goldTotal - 40;
            System.out.println("You now have: " + bomb + " Bomb(s)!\n"
                    + "You now have: " + goldTotal + " gold!\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You do not have the required level or gold"
                    + "need to buy this weapon!");
        }
    }
    if(commandShop.equalsIgnoreCase("Items")){
        System.out.print("What do you want to buy?\n"
                + "1. Small HP-Potion - 10g Heal: 20 (lvl: 0)\n"
                + "2. Mana-Potion - 20g Full-Mana (lvl: 1)\n"
                + "3. Large HP-Potion - 40g Heal: 40 (lvl: 2)\n"
                + "Choice: ");
        commandShop = console.next();
        System.out.println();
        if(commandBuy == 1 && goldTotal >= 10){
            hpPotion++;
            items++;
            goldTotal = goldTotal - 10;
            System.out.println("You now have: "
                    + hpPotion + " Small HP-Potion(s)!\n"
                    + "You now have: " + goldTotal + " gold!\n");
        }
        if(commandBuy == 2 && goldTotal >= 20 && level >= 1){
            mpPotion++;
            items++;
            goldTotal = goldTotal - 20;
            System.out.println("You now have: "
                    + mpPotion + " Mana-Potion(s)!\n"
                    + "You now have: " + goldTotal + " gold!\n");
        }
        if(commandBuy == 3 && goldTotal >= 40 && level >= 2){
            potion++;
            items++;
            goldTotal = goldTotal - 40;
            System.out.println("You now have: "
                    + potion + " Large HP-Potions(s)!\n"
                    + "You now have: " + goldTotal + " gold!\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You do not have the required level or gold"
                    + "need to buy this item!");
        }
    }
    if(commandShop.equalsIgnoreCase("Magic")){
        System.out.println("Not implemented yet!\n");
    }
    }
    while(!commandShop.equalsIgnoreCase("Leave"));
}

public static void game(){   // last static void used - User input For Home
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
        System.out.print("-----------------------\n"
                + "What do you want to do?\n"
                + "Hunt | Shop | Sleep | Skills |\nStats | LevelUp"
                + " | Inventory |\n"
                + "Choice: ");
        command=console.next();
        System.out.println();
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("Hunt")){
            int monsterChance = (int)(1 + Math.random()*100-1+1);
            if(monsterChance <= 50){
                huntRat();
            }
            if(monsterChance <=90 && monsterChance > 50){
                huntWeasel();
            }
            if(monsterChance <=100 && monsterChance > 90){
                huntBear();
            }
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("Sleep")){
            hp = 100;
            mana = 10;
            System.out.println("You HP is now at 100"
                    + " and your Mana is at 10!");
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("Stats")){
            System.out.println("You have: " + expTotal 
                    + " exp!\nYou have: " + goldTotal + " gold!\n"
                    + "Your level is: " + level);
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("LevelUp")){
            if(expTotal >= 100){
                level++;
                System.out.println("CONGRATS! You have leveled up!"
                        + "\nYour level is: " + level);
                expTotal = expTotal - 100;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("You don't have enough exp! Hunt more!");
    }
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("Shop")){
            System.out.println("Welcome to the shops!");
            shop();
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("Inventory")){
            System.out.println("You have: " + arrow + " arrow(s)\n"
                    + "You have: " + shuriken + " shuriken(s)\n"
                    + "You have: " + bomb + " bomb(s)\n"
                    + "You have: " + hpPotion + " Small Hp-Potion(s)\n"
                    + "You have: " + mpPotion + " Mana-Potion(s)\n"
                    + "You have: " + potion + " Large Hp-Potion(s)\n");
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("Skills")){
            Skills skillObject = new Skills();
            skillObject.skills();
        }
    }
    while(!command.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"));         //how to stop game
    System.out.println("You have left the game without saving!");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    title();
    game();
}
```

}

Comment: Java Swing is a good way to start... You can use it to build a GUI for your game.

Comment: maybe this example can help you... http://stackoverflow.com/a/27876110/3615725 ... you just need to redirect all your `System.out.println` to the TextArea... and all your Scanner inputs from TextField

Comment: How would i go about redirecting them? (Sorry im new)

Comment: well, your `System.out.println` would become `frame.textArea.append("text here");` and your input would be the the text from `frame.textField.getText();` . Also you oould need to make the frame visible by your game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to do it with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876110/3615725) then you will need to do this in your game class

```
private ChanDown frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new ChanDown();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    title();
    game();
}
```

and change all your `System.out.println("text here");` to `frame.textArea.append("\n" + text here);`

remove your Scanner, and just take all the input from this code:

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) { //this is key code for pressing enter
                // do the code you want to do when you get the text entered
            }
        }
    });
```

but it is obvious that you will need to do a lot of adjustments in order to get all that working as intended...

Comment: So, iv'e been trying to do this, but I can't figure out how to display the frame.textArea.append in the window.... and I have to make the private ChanDown() **Which I renamed to Client() and switched all the others too** into a Private static Client()    or else it gives an error that says "non-static variable frame cannot be referenced from a static context." Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: well it's a bit tricky, but I could help you out in a chat room interactively... try making textArea static

Comment: Yea, I might need some help, because that does not seem to work either.

Comment: EDIT: I joined, but i can't talk in it, I don't have the reputation for it.

Comment: Thank you, and maybe some other time you can show me how to use the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following in a Batch file

```
@echo off
java -jar TextBasedRPG.jar
```

and tell your friends to run the .bat file.

Comment: I know that, but I was hoping that there could be some other way to just run from the .jar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be run by double-clicking the JAR if it kicked up a JFrame.

Have a look at https://github.com/mafagafogigante/dungeon, a project of mine that uses a JFrame as a terminal-like window (also a text-based game). You can download a compiled JAR file from the releases tab.